# Encoding error in content get from open-uri in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby, character-encoding, open-uri

In some cases when I use `open` to get a web page in Ruby the content of the page has an encoding error. Example:

```
open("http://www.google.com.br").read
```

Chars like `ç` and `ã` are replaced by `?`

How can I get the right chars?

Comment: are you using utf-8 for your characters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this seems to work:

```
require 'iconv'
i = Iconv.new('UTF-8','LATIN1')
i.iconv(open('http://google.com.br').read)
```

Comment: That will work as long as the encoding is consistent throughout the document. HTML from a site that generates its own content is *usually* consistent. HTML from a site that aggregates content from multiple places can end up being all over the map, for instance, Google.

Comment: That errors' undefined method `read' for #<Iconv:0x1166c2de0>

Comment: it works for me both in ruby-1.8.7 and ruby-1.9.0. Also, the error is saying "undefined method read for Iconv", but I'm not applying read to any Iconv instance...

Answer (score 0):

Running Ruby 1.9.2 here. Your code yields HTML which contains words like this:

```
Configura\xE7\xF5es
```

So on my work machine at least (Vista, using Windows CMD console), it returns HTML escaped characters.

Also, as far as I know, Ruby 1.9.2 is "almost" fully Unicode compliant, so I am guessing you shouldn't have UTF-8 issues unless your console cannot handle printing UTF-8 characters.

Hope that helps.